# Передача данных с мобильного приложения на сервер в БД

Tags: java, android, sql

Здравствуйте. Не мог найти подобный вопрос. Смотрите: у меня есть мобильное приложение, написанное на Java. При нажатии на кнопку данные должны переноситься на сервер, который находится, скажем так, не рядом со мной. У меня есть имя сервера, логин, пароль и название самой БД (SQL), куда должны переноситься данные. Куда мне вписывать логин, пароль и т.д. в коде? Я что-то не понимаю. Как это должно выглядеть?

Comment: Начните [отсюда](https://habrahabr.ru/company/e-Legion/blog/265405/) - ключевые слова для гугления: *restful, retrofit*

Comment: Android Post Request + AsynkTask **Barmaley**, Retrofit для новичка сложно ещё API есть готовый?

Comment: Я только списки не обработал в приложении.

Comment: Прошу прощения, видимо, не то API имелось ввиду, о чём я подумал)

Comment: Прямо в серверную БД писать не получится из мобильного приложения, нужно еще серверное API между ними. Поищите и почитайте что-нить о клиент-серверных приложениях.

Answer (score 0):

Напрямую вносить данные из приложения в БД, скажем по мягче, плохой тон, если эта БД не расположена на самом устройстве.
Вам не обойтись серверной частью, которая будет принимать запросы с приложения и изменять данные в БД.
Классический путь: Мобильное приложение <-(REST API)-> Сервер <-> БД